# zf2 build paginator from existing object or array

Tags: php, orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I have a problem with paginator in my zf2 project

I have 3 SQL's with fist SQL I am building a paginator.

After that I am doing `foreach()` and put some new info from sql query 2 & 3 to this paginator object ( its work fine)

The problem is that I would like to sort data by column that I became from query 2 & 3.

1. Is it possible to create a paginator from an object?
2. Is it possible to sort an existing paginator object?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You can create a new Paginator using the ArrayAdapter (or any custom Adapter implementing AdapterInterface).
2. No. Sorting is not the responsibility of paginator itself, although, various adapters DO allow for sorting criteria to be provided when they fetch their data.